# Delphi - Is TDictionary thread safe

Tags: multithreading, delphi, tcp, thread-safety, indy

My idea is to use TDictionary to manage client connections on IdTCPServer. Here is a simple example code (not tested) for understanding purposes:

```
var
  Dic: TDictionary<string, TIdContext>;

procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Dic := TDictionary<string, TIdContext>.Create;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Dic.Free;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.TCPServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Hostname: string;
begin
  Hostname := UpperCase(GStack.HostByAddress(AContext.Binding.PeerIP));
  if not Dic.ContainsKey(Hostname) then Dic.Add(Hostname, AContext);
end;

procedure TfrmMain.TCPServerDisconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Hostname: string;
begin
  Hostname := UpperCase(GStack.HostByAddress(AContext.Binding.PeerIP));
  if Dic.ContainsKey(Hostname) then
  begin
    Dic[Hostname].Free;
    Dic.Remove(Hostname);
  end;
end;
```

Is this code thread safe?

Comment: Are you sure that you are meant to destroy the contexts? And if so, are you sure you aren't going to leak some?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I understood you point, but I dind't test this code. It is just for understanding purposes... Thanks!

Comment: As a rule of thumb: Every class of RTL, VCL, FMX is **not threadsafe**, if it is, you will see it looking at the class name starting with `TThreaded...` as for [`TThreadedQueue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TThreadedQueue).

Comment: It's far more complex than that. There is no single thing called thread safe. A dictionary is thread safe if you never mutate the dictionary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a word:  **No**.

If you inspect the source of **TDictionary** you should quickly realise that there is no provision for thread-safety in the implementation itself.  Even if it were, by having discrete calls to a **Dic** instance you have potential race conditions to contend with:

```
  if Dic.ContainsKey(Hostname) then
  begin

    // In theory the Hostname key may be removed by another thread before you 
    //  get a chance to do this : ...

    Dic[Hostname].Free;
    Dic.Remove(Hostname);
  end;
```

You need to make your own use of **Dic** thread safe, and fortunately in this sort of example this is easily achieved using a monitor on the object itself:

```
MonitorEnter(Dic);
try
  if not Dic.ContainsKey(Hostname) then 
    Dic.Add(Hostname, AContext);

finally
  MonitorExit(Dic);
end;


// ....


MonitorEnter(Dic);
try
  if Dic.ContainsKey(Hostname) then
  begin
    Dic[Hostname].Free;
    Dic.Remove(Hostname);
  end;

finally
  MonitorExit(Dic);
end;
```

If you are not familiar with monitors in Delphi, in simple terms you can think of a monitor as a ready-to-use critical section supported by every **TObject** descendant (in older versions of Delphi which did not support these monitors you could have achieved the same thing with an explicit critical section).

Comment: more efficiency when removing by using `TObjectDictionary` and `Remove`. Avoids 3 lookups when 1 suffices. Of course that assumes that it is right to free the contexts, which it is not. Once the `Free` has been removed then a simple single call to `Remove` suffices. +1

Answer (score 3):

To answer your specific question - no, `TDictionary` is NOT thread-safe, so you must protect access to it.

Your code is not handling the possibility of multiple clients behind a proxy/router connecting to the same server.  They will all have the same `PeerIP` and `HostName` values.  Those values are not unique enough by themselves to identify clients.  You need to create your own unique identifiers, for instance by having your clients login to your server with a username, and then use that as your dictionary key instead.

And lastly, DO NOT free `TIdContext` objects!  They are owned by `TIdTCPServer` and will be freed automatically after the `OnDisconnect` event handler has exited.

Comment: Ok @Remy Lebeau... It was just another idea to manage the client connections. The code is not complete, just for understanding purposes. But you answered what I need to know, about TDictionary be thread safe. Thank you!